# convert .txt file to .csv file using python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRLqv.png)AR              =  0.9995         N2              =   0.000           HE              =   0.000
KR              =   0.000         H2              =  6.3998E-08       H               =  4.2639E-15
H2O             =   0.000        CO2             =   0.000           CO              =   0.000
CH4             =  6.6510E-08    CH3             =  8.0334E-10       CH2             =  6.7005E-12

my text file is in this form where i would like to transform it into a csv file where the names od the species is in a row and the corresponding numbers in a row
I would really appreciate any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lydxe.png)

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=15MK_sRDOuYD9dTX_2FMmCK7Mdvc9CMfn : this is my text file that I want to transform

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: We cannot help you by just looking at data and not your code.

Comment: import pandas as pd

# reading the given csv file 
# and creating dataframe
account = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\time_dependent_pressure_model\C3H6_PD\1141K.txt',
                      delimiter = '=')
  
# store dataframe into csv file
account.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\time_dependent_pressure_model\C3H6_PD\1141K.csv',
               index = None)

Comment: the problem there's space between the value of AR and N2 and likewise for other data so it's separating where there is equal as a column  so I'm having 4 columns one for Ar and the other 0.9995 N2, 0.000 HE, and lastly 0 . I want to transform it in a way where the species are in the first row and there corresponding values below them in another row. I tried transpose too it didn't work

Comment: It might be easier to load this into a `python` dictionary then pass it into `pandas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transformed the file into a row, as mentioned in question

```html
import re
import pandas as pd
#read the file from a txt
#list of files
list_files = ['data1.txt','data2.txt']
for j in list_files:
    f = open(j, "r")
    data = f.readlines()
    # joining the text and removing newline and space
    string = " ".join(data)
    string = " ".join(re.sub(r'[\n]', '', string).split())
    string = string.replace(' = ', '|').replace('= ', '|')
    data = {}
    list_string = string.split(" ")
    for i in list_string:
        k = i.split("|")
        print(k)
        data[k[0]] = float(k[1])
    f.close()
    df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    df.to_csv(f"{j.split('.txt')[0]}.csv", index=False)
```

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gqE0KX0Qw1o7SBegv1riIHSczXhhZA4Ot2oYOaEKZN4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: data[k[0]]=float(k[1])

IndexError: list index out of range. It gave me this.

Comment: @Farah can please share your text file then it will help, above code works for the text shared above

Comment: how can I share my text file

Comment: @Farah just upload the file to google drive and share the link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=15MK_sRDOuYD9dTX_2FMmCK7Mdvc9CMfn

Comment: this is my text file

Comment: @Farah I transformed the text file into a row, check the file, are you looking for this output?

Comment: @Farah please close the question

Comment: You definitely want to do an `f.close()` for completeness when you're done reading in the file.

Comment: Can I ask one more question. if I need to do this for more than one file how can I do it instead of uploading one by one @SebinSunny

Comment: Not sure what you mean by uploading. Aren't these files locally available on your computer? You would want to gather the list of files into a `list` and do a `for` loop.

Comment: @Farah create a list of files, and iterate through the list, update the code; also the structure of the file should be the same otherwise, it will throw an error

Comment: I have this text file in this google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/15k0cUOPXBm3SAR4cxwme8zPGF6256bay/view?usp=drivesdk  . I want to extract from this txt file only REACTOR GAS PHASE MOLE FRACTIONS starting from line including Ar to the line including C10H6(C2H)CH3-12 at 'Transient Solution at Time =   1.0000E-02 seconds'. can u help me ? @SebinSunny thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps,

1. Split the texts appropriately
2. Make a new csv file
3. Use Python's csv module to add the data into it

Let me know if you are not familiar with this kind of stuff. Then I would be more thorough.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this stuff on python if u can explain more to me what to use. thanks in advance

Comment: @Farah I can't really understand how exactly you want to make the `csv`. Can you show an example of the `csv`?

Comment: I added two images one for the txt file I have and one how I want it to look like in csv

Comment: there's a way to do this or no?